# List Recursive Predicates, advanced

Tags: prolog

Just going through some tutorials and I found some advanced recursive procedurs like flatten. I have tried to google to find similar examples that involve multiple recursions (head tail) but could not get the result I required.

Could you infer some predicates or tutorials that cover advanced list recusions (on both head, tail)?

Comment: `flatten/2` is an interesting predicate, but I don't think recursion "on both head, tail" generally makes much sense, and in any case isn't where you should be looking to "advance" your understanding of recursion.  Advanced techniques that come to mind are *difference lists* and *accumulators*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to expand a bit on what @hardmath is saying, let's look at the definition of lists:

- Base case: `[]`
- Inductive case: `[Head|Tail]`

What makes this a recursive data structure is that `Tail` is also a list. So when you see `[1,2,3]`, you're also seeing `[1|[2|[3|[]]]]`. Let's prove it:

```
?- X = [1|[2|[3|[]]]].
X = [1, 2, 3].
```

So more "advanced" forms of recursion are forms that either involve more complex recursive data types or more complex computations. The next recursive data type most people are exposed to are binary trees, and binary trees have the nice property that they have two branches per node, so let's look at trees for a second.

First we need a nice definition like the definition from lists. I propose the following:

- Base case: `empty`
- Inductive case: `tree(LeftBranch, Value, RightBranch)`

Now let's create some example trees just to get a feel for how they look:

```
% this is like the empty list: no data
empty

% this is your basic tree of one node
tree(empty, 1, empty)

% this is a tree with two nodes
tree(tree(empty, 1, empty), 2, empty).
```

Structurally, the last example there would probably look something like this:

```
   2
  /
 1
```

Now let's make a fuller example with several levels. Let's build this tree:

```
     10
   /    \
  5      9
 / \    /  \
4   6  7   14
```

In our Prolog syntax it's going to look like this:

```
tree(tree(tree(empty, 4, empty), 5, tree(empty,  6, empty)), 
     10, 
     tree(tree(empty, 7, empty), 9, tree(empty, 14, empty)))
```

The first thing we're going to want is a way to add up the size of the tree. Like with lists, we need to consider our base case and then our inductive cases.

```
% base case
tree_size(empty, 0).

% inductive case
tree_size(tree(Left, _, Right), Size) :-
  tree_size(Left, LeftSize),
  tree_size(Right, RightSize),
  Size is LeftSize + RightSize + 1.
```

For comparison, let's look at list length:

```
% base case
length([], 0).

% inductive case
length([_|Rest], Length) :- 
  length(Rest, LengthOfRest), 
  Length is LengthOfRest + 1.
```

**Edit**: @false points out that though the above is intuitive, a version with better logical properties can be produced by changing the inductive case to:

```
length([_|Rest], Length) :-
  length(Rest, LengthOfRest),
  succ(LengthOfRest, Length).
```

So you can see the hallmarks of recursively processing data structures clearly by comparing these two:

- You are given a recursive data structure, defined in terms of base cases and inductive cases.
- You write the base of your rule to handle the base case.

  This step is usually obvious; in the case of length or size, your data structure will have a base case that is empty so you just have to associate zero with that case.
- You write the inductive step of your rule.

  The inductive step takes the recursive case of the data structure and handles whatever that case adds, and combining that with the result of recursively calling your rule to process "the rest" of the data structure.

Because lists are only recursive in one direction there's only one recursive call in most list processing rules. Because trees have two branches there can be one or two depending on whether you need to process the whole tree or just go down one path. Both lists and trees effectively have two "constructors," so most rules will have two bodies, one to handle the empty case and one to handle the inductive case. More complex structures, such as language grammars, can have more than two basic patterns, and usually you'll either process all of them separately or you'll just be seeking out one pattern in particular.

As an exercise, you may want to try writing `search`, `insert`, `height`, `balance` or `is_balanced` and various other tree queries to get more familiar with the process.

Comment: Now that's what I call expanding!  Mine, obviously, was the `flatten` version :-}

Comment: @hardmath Thanks! I am a lot better at expanding than flattening! :) I only hope it did help.

Comment: But your definition of `length/2` only illustrates one use case &mdash; when the length is known. And it is very inefficient for `dllength(L,N), N > 10000` and the like.

Comment: @false I appreciate your relentlessness, but the questioner is interested in seeing illustrations of recursion, not writing high-performance Prolog for mission-critical applications. One step at a time.

Comment: Then stick to successor-arithmetics and the like.

Comment: @false successor arithmetic has nothing to do with lists. Every Prolog book shows code just like this. Remember that not everyone comes here one level below you. Many people are just getting started and don't need to see all the fine print on day one.

Comment: You are using (is)/2 which is very sensible to instantiations and thus is used in manners that show very poor termination properties. Take your length/2 which does not work in the other direction. With s(X) (or even better with clpfd) you get *both* directions without any clever reasoning. I use only clpfd in courses. But s(X) is quite good too.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood you. I thought you were saying I should not use lists recursively at all! :) I'll update the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I did not mean to use succ/2. Use either s(X) or clpfd. clpfd is best, but you have to use SWI, YAP or SICStus

Comment: Maybe you are interested in [reading this](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/papers/PDF/#2008-fdpe)

Comment: I'll give it a read later tonight. Feel free to correct the answer with `s(X)` if you want it fixed now. I don't see exactly what you mean if you don't mean `succ/2`.